# How can I handle an array where elements contain spaces in Bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop

Let's say I have a file named `tmp.out` that contains the following:

```
c:\My files\testing\more files\stuff\test.exe
c:\testing\files here\less files\less stuff\mytest.exe
```

I want to put the contents of that file into an array and I do it like so:

```
ARRAY=( `cat tmp.out` )
```

I then run this through a for loop like so

```
for i in ${ARRAY[@]};do echo ${i}; done
```

But the output ends up like this:

```
c:\My
files\testing\more
files\stuff\test.sas
c:\testing\files
here\less
files\less
stuff\mytest.sas
```

and I want the output to be:

```
c:\My files\testing\more files\stuff\test.exe
c:\testing\files here\less files\less stuff\mytest.exe
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: For your simplified question you can avoid an array and use the loop of @choroba with `echo "${line}"`. I hope you can implement a solution for your more complex real life quest without an array!

Answer (score 4):

In order to iterate over the values in an array, you need to quote the array expansion to avoid word splitting:

```
for i in "${values[@]}"; do
```

Of course, you should also quote the use of the value:

```
  echo "${i}"
done
```

That doesn't answer the question of how to get the lines of a file into an array in the first place. If you have bash 4.0, you can use the `mapfile` builtin:

```
mapfile -t values < tmp.out
```

Otherwise, you'd need to temporarily change the value of `IFS` to a single newline, or use a loop over the `read` builtin.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the IFS variable, the Internal Field Separator. Set it to empty string to split the contents on newlines only:

```
while IFS= read -r line ; do
    ARRAY+=("$line")
done < tmp.out
```

`-r` is needed to keep the literal backslashes.

Comment: `IFS` is for internal line whitespace. You don't need it for this. You do want to set it to blank though `IFS=` to prevent word-splitting collapsing runs of multiple spaces though.

Comment: That said for bash 4+ `mapfile` is better as [Bash FAQ 005](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005#Loading_lines_from_a_file_or_stream) says.

Comment: @chepner: The reaction was relevant for the previous version of my reply which was indeed wrong.

Comment: Doesn't Bash have [`read -a ARRAY`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-read) for reading into an array?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: `read -a A` puts the individual words taken from one line of stdin into the array `A`. `mapfile -t A` puts the individual lines from stdin into the array.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a array` does indeed work (if the data has no NULs), but mapfile is much cleaner.

Comment: @rici, sure, but as the user you have control of what constitutes a "line" and a "word". :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Not with mapfile, irritatingly. But in this case, it's a lot handier.

Comment: OK; `read -a array` is not helpful in this context, though it exists and may sometimes be useful.  Thanks.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a array` indeed works, but its exit status is 1 (as it encounters end of file).

Comment: @choroba, fair point; one would want to NUL-terminate the input to prevent that. Which isn't hard to do: `< <(cat tmp.out; printf '\0')`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I don't think I agree with "not helpful"; it's a bit harder to use correctly (for the use case at hand), but if you need compatibility with bash 3.x, that extra effort is often worthwhile.

Answer (score 2):

Another simple way to control word-splitting is by controlling the Internal Field Separator (`IFS`):

```
#!/bin/bash

oifs="$IFS"  ## save original IFS
IFS=$'\n'    ## set IFS to break on newline

array=( $( <dat/2lines.txt ) )  ## read lines into array

IFS="$oifs"  ## restore original IFS

for ((i = 0; i < ${#array[@]}; i++)) do
    printf "array[$i] : '%s'\n" "${array[i]}"
done
```

**Input**

```
$ cat dat/2lines.txt
c:\My files\testing\more files\stuff\test.exe
c:\testing\files here\less files\less stuff\mytest.exe
```

**Output**

```
$ bash arrayss.sh
array[0] : 'c:\My files\testing\more files\stuff\test.exe'
array[1] : 'c:\testing\files here\less files\less stuff\mytest.exe'
```

Comment: Assigning a shell variable in a subshell isn't going to be of much use.

Comment: @rici - the solution in this case is to move the process out of the subshell. Fixed.

Comment: Unless you turn off shell globbing, a line containing only `*` would be replaced with a list of filenames.

Comment: That is something I did not consider given the sample input, but a very valid point. So if that is a possibility with the data, we would need a `set -f` prior to redirecting the file into the array and a `set +f` following.